# What is vi editor shortcut for "comment out the current line where the cursor is" for .tex files?

Tags: shortcut

I want to know whether I can comment out the current line for LaTeX file, but have kept falling to google it.

Answer (score 0):

It's & (ampersand)! NOBODY seems to have written this on any website in the world! - At least, I've failed to Google it!

Comment: Really? https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%26 Is this with a certain plugin?

Comment: @DaiBowen not as long as I know. I don't recollect that I've installed any plug-in. it works even with pure vi editor (not macvim or something like that).

Comment: In normal/visual mode `&` attemps the last `:s` substitution as expected from `:help &`, including in compatible mode. Perhaps your last substitution was something like `:s/^/%`?

Comment: @DaiBowen You're right! :( do you happen to know, then, the shortcut for "comment out the current line"? - btw, I'm totally satisfied with using the trick (that I found accidentally).